# Mixed Content warnings when loader Twitter API data on an SSL site

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using the [Twitter API PHP wrapper](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) to load content from the Twitter API onto my secure WordPress site. But I'm getting mixed content warnings in the Chrome console as the data it's returning isn't secure.

Is this something I can safely ignore or is there a way to load secure content through the Twitter API?

Answer (score 0):

The twitter API javascript files or maybe even an image are being referenced via http://. Check all files you target on the twitter website and change the path to https://. If you post the code you are using i can help better.

If changing to https doesnt help, press f12 and open up the developer tools. Any ssl errors will be in the console. This will help you find the files that are being referenced as http instead of https

Comment: Seems to work. All the images are loaded from `http://twimg.com` - are all images loaded from there - i.e. will this string replacement work for all URLs?

Comment: You could use a string replace, but you would best find the source of the includes and change the change manually.

Comment: Not sure I follow. How can I find the source? I'm getting these `http` URLs passed back to me through the Twitter API.

Comment: normally with any of the major APIs there is a single file you include and it will then add whatever else it needs. So if i include http://twitter.com/somejavascript.js all the images will in turn be added as http://, but if you add it as https:// the images should also be secure